# React: Invoke redirect to page, and pass parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building my first React app.
In my code, I redirect to another page (a component) using

```
browserHistory.push(pathToMyComponent)
```

I also have tried out the react-router Link-element. The Link element enables me to pass data to the target component without having it showing up in the URL, like this:

```
<Link to={`/myComponent/${someData}`}>
```

But now I don't want to create a link. Instead I want to perform some operations when pushing a button, and then redirect with some calculated data.
How do I do this?

Edit:
Here is my code. In loginpage, the user can perform a facebook login. What I want is to redirect the user to the lobby after login succeeded. I want to pass the userid to the lobby.

```
<Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
   <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
   <Route path="/lobby" component={Lobby}/>
</Router>
```

This is what I wrote after reading your answer. When this is executed, the log prints `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null`

```
this.context.router.push({ //browserHistory.push should also work here
     pathname: '/lobby',
     state: {userid: authData.uid}
});
```

Edit2: You mean like this? It gives syntax error.

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {

  contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  };
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
...
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a normal button with an `onClick` event handler which would fire a function. In this function you can calculate the data that you want and then finally do a `push` to your router.

Example:

```
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={this._handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
    ...
  );
}

_handleButtonClick = () => {
  //calculate your data here
  //then redirect:
  this.context.router.push({ //browserHistory.push should also work here
    pathname: pathToMyComponent,
    state: {yourCalculatedData: data}
  }); 
}
```

You'll then be able to get that data from your `location`'s `state`.

Check out the docs for this [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link).

**EDIT:**

To use `this.context.router` add this inside your components' class:

```
static contextTypes = { 
  router: React.PropTypes.object 
}
```

Comment: I have not worked with context before. The docs say that it is an experimental feature and is likely to be changed in the future. Is there no other way? This feels like a basic need in many applikations.

Comment: @hellogoodnight Where in the docs did you see that? `context` is the way `react-router` devs use, so it's quite official at this point.

Comment: Not really, I have a hard time figuring out how to work with the router.context- object. Would you mind taking a look at my code? I'll edit the question

Comment: @hellogoodnight Try the above edit I made. It works only for versions 2.0.0 and above of `react-router`

Comment: Were exactly should this be added? Inside the constructor? The console says that the keyword `static` is reserverd

Comment: No, outside. `static` can be omited though. Try without static.

Comment: no I could not make it work. I figured out that I actually did not have to pass the data to the other component, I could get the data from the db istead.
However, it is very wierd that I could not make the code you gave me to compile. I will for sure need this thing in the future...

Comment: Oh, bummer. I was gonna say I think I may know the solution.

Comment: Please tell me and I'll try it when I get home

Comment: I don't think we tried `var contextTypes = {`. try that (with/without `static`)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy trick here:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/profile",
    data: data // your data array of objects
  }}
>
  
//in /profile
  render() {
  const { data } = useLocation().data;
  return (
    // render logic here
  )
}
```